# sha256 C# PHP почему разные хэши?

Tags: php, c#, sha256

```
c#
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] buff = new byte[size];
rng.GetBytes(buff);
var salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(buff));
var passBytes = GetBytesFromPassword(password);
HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();
var saltBytes = passBytes.Concat(salt).ToArray();
var HASH = algorithm.ComputeHash(saltBytes);
```

Сразу предупреждаю, в С# я не понимаю но как я понял должно было бы быть так  `$hash = hash_hmac('sha256',$password,$salt,true);`

но по сути хэши разные.

Comment: алгоритмы разные

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста SHA256Managed это какой алгоритм? Где я могу разобраться в этом?

Comment: [sha265](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) и [hmac_sha256](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) - это разные вещи. Для того чтоб были одинаковыми вам нужно использовать либо просто sha256 либо sha256 с hmac обёрткой, и там и там одинаковый.

Comment: Я пробовал sha256 вот так hash('sha256',$password.$salt);

Comment: `hash('sha256', $password.$salt, true` p.s. `salt` как на php генериш?

Comment: SALT - беру из БД, смысл следующий: так генерились хэши в бд для пользователей. И в бд лежить хэш пароля и соль. Я пытался сравнить введенный пользователем пароль с сохраненным в БД и я точно знаю все пароли. Так вот они эти хэши не совпадают

Comment: Спасибо всем, закрываем тему